# Symfony2: Showing table with additional combobox column

Tags: php, symfony, combobox

I'm new in Symfony. I have entity which have 5 fields. Want to show all database table rows in table with additional 6th cell which is combobox and values of it is dependent from count of parts to sell (0..countOfPart). I have two ideas:

1. I show it on my view in table with added in twig 6th column. Then i want to (after clicking some link) pass data from my table to controller, but I dont know how get value from combobox/select cell.
2. Show it via form, but dont know how to make table with it.

Here is my current table part twig view:

```
{% for part in parts %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ part.Part.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ part.Part.manufactory }}</td>
                <td>{{ part.Part.carModel }}</td>
                <td>{{ part.Part.countOfPart }}</td>
                <td>{{ part.Part.pricePerUnit }}</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="selectedPartCount">
                        {% for i in 0..part.Part.countOfPart %}
                            <option value={{ i }}>{{ i }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
{% endfor %}
```